# How to get a file from a docker instance

Tags: docker

I started a docker instance like so

```
docker run -it ubuntu:14.04.4 bash
```

I performed some tasks within the instance and now I'd like to get the resulting files. How do I get the files without using ftp/scp to connect to an external site somewhere else? Is there a way to mount a USB stick or something which could be copied to easily?

Comment: Did you see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/?

Comment: That won't work if you didn't use any of the volume commands at the start

Comment: How about this https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/01/13/docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/?

Comment: Volumes are the "right way" to do this kind of thing in most cases, but this covers the edge case where you forget, or don't know about docker volumes

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer and it involves using an additional terminal window, hopefully this will help others:

Open a new terminal window and run `docker ps` to get the container id. with the container id in-hand, using `5d0a816af9a8` for example, use this command to copy the tarball / file you want:

```
docker cp 5d0a816af9a8:/mybuilddir/myfile.tar.gz /home/me
```

With `/home/me` being the destination on the host system.

Comment: Would you accept your own answer as this what worked for you. It will help others find the solution.